# Java - URLConnections stop connecting?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, urlconnection

I'm working on a homework assignment that has the purpose of showing how increasing the number of threads can help or hurt a program's performance.  The basic idea is to thread individual requests for data from a website, then determine how long it takes to perform all the queries when one runs *n* queries simultaneously.

I think I have the threading and the clocking done properly, but something odd is going on with the requests.  I am using `java.net.URLConnection` to get connect to the databases.  My first three thousand or so connections will succeed and load.  Then, several hundred or so calls fail without any evidence of Java having tried for the specified timeout period.

The code I run in a thread is as follows:

```
/* This code to get the contents from an URL was adapted from a
 * StackOverflow question found at http://goo.gl/QPqR4 .
 */
private static String loadContent(String address) throws Exception {
  String toReturn = "";

  try {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    con.setReadTimeout(5000);
    InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(stream, "ISO-8859-1");

    while (true) {
      int ch = r.read();
      if (ch < 0) {
        break;
      }
      toReturn += (char) ch;
    }

    r.close();
    stream.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(address + ": " + e.getMessage());
    throw e;
  }

  return toReturn;
}
```

The code for running the threads is as follows.  The `NormalPerformance` class is one I wrote to simplify calculating the mean and variance of a series of observations.

```
/* This code is patterned after code provided by my professor.
 */
private static NormalPerformance performExperiment(int threads, int runs)
  throws Exception
{
  NormalPerformance toReturn = new NormalPerformance();

  for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
    final List<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();
    for (int j = 0; j < URLS.length; j++) {
      final String url = URLS[i];
      tasks.add(new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() throws Exception {
          loadContent(url);
          return null;
        }
      });
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    final ExecutorService exectuorPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    executorPool.invokeAll(tasks);
    executorPool.shutdown();
    double time = (System.nano() - start) / 1000000000.;
    toReturn.addObservation(time);

    System.out.println("" + threads + " " + (i + 1) + ": " + time);
  }

  return toReturn;
}
```

Why am I seeing this odd pattern of success and failure?  Even stranger, there are times when killing the program and restarting does nothing to stop the run of failures.  I've tried things like forcing threads to sleep, calling `System.gc()`, and increasing the connection and reading timeout values, but none of these, alone or combined, have fixed this.

How can I guarantee that my connections have the best chance possible of connecting?

Environment:
Windows 7 64-bit,
Eclipse Juno 64-bit,
JRE 7

Comment: You *should* try *BufferedReader* and *StringBuffer*.

Comment: The error message printouts are formatted like "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=ABT&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv: connect timed out".  The only part that changes is the preceding URL.

Comment: In fact you *must* use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`. Otherwise you will find that most of your time is spent concatenating strings, which isn't what you're supposed to be measuring.